# How to make an arrow character as seen in the attached image?

Tags: html, css, unicode

I'm working to reproduce a design I found, the design shows a text arrow like so:

[image]

Any idea how to make that arrow? The obvious `>` looks wrong:

[image]

Comment: Some fonts have a character like that `›`, but you may need a special font/SVG/etc icon instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your designer used [`chevron-right` from Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons/chevron-right?style=solid). You can install it by adding a stylesheet from the [Font Awesome CDN](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/customizing-wordpress/snippets/setup-cdn-webfont) like I've done below or through any of the [other setup options](https://fontawesome.com/start). Then, you can reference the icon on the page by copying the icon code that the [Font Awesome documentation](https://fontawesome.com/icons/chevron-right?style=solid) supplies you with.

Here's a demo where I've tried to recreate your image:

```css
:root {
  background-color: #22272A;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #BCBDBD;
}

.fa-chevron-right {
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
HIKING <span class="fas fa-chevron-right"></span>

<!-- External Libraries -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vp86vTRFVJgpjF9jiIGPEEqYqlDwgyBgEF109VFjmqGmIY/Y4HV4d3Gp2irVfcrp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

In production code, you may want to choose a different installation method for [performance considerations](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/performance) that takes into account your page's needs - for example, choosing to import SVGs with JavaScript if you don't have a very large number of icons to display.

Answer (score -1):

Try http://fontawesome.io

They have lots of icons - Search for 'fa-angle-right ' on this page: http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet

Otherwise, you can use a png or an svg.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  body {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <p>I will display &#10095;</p>
  <p>I will display &#x276F;</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could maybe add some explanation about the characters you use ?…